leaflet() empty geometry Error Don't know how to get polygon data from object of class XY,GEOMETRYCOLLECTION,sfg
I was using the leaflet package in R, and I had this error (in the title) that took some time to track down. I could not find the exact error or solution posted, so I am posting.
I was using a shapefile provided by a third party. It contained empty geometries, which caused the error in the title of this post.
Example:
library(leaflet)
library(sf)

# get county shapefile for the state of Virginia from the tigris package
va_shp <- tigris::counties(state = 51,
                           year = 2019)

# to easily make some empty geometries, simplify geometry too much
va_shp_oversimplified <- va_shp |>
  st_simplify(dTolerance = 10000) # note: this tolerance is too big for these small geographies

# leaflet returns the error
leaflet(va_shp_oversimplified) |>
  addPolygons()

"Error in to_ring.default(x) : 
  Don't know how to get polygon data from object of class XY,GEOMETRYCOLLECTION,sfg"


Solution:
The key to the error is the 'GEOMETRYCOLLECTION' part. Some of the geometry values are 'GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY'.
# check if any geometries are empty
any(sf::st_is_empty(va_shp_oversimplified))

# remove empty geometries to map without the error
va_shp_oversimplified |>
  subset(!st_is_empty(geometry)) |>
  leaflet() |>
  addPolygons()


Or, if there are empty geometries, there might be another issue going on upstream, so simply removing the empty ones is not always the solution.

Solution:
The key to the error is the 'GEOMETRYCOLLECTION' part. Some of the geometry values are 'GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY'.
# check if any geometries are empty
any(sf::st_is_empty(va_shp_oversimplified))

# remove empty geometries to map without the error
va_shp_oversimplified |>
  subset(!st_is_empty(geometry)) |>
  leaflet() |>
  addPolygons()

Or, if there are empty geometries, there might be another issue going on upstream, so simply removing the empty ones is not always the solution.
